# aggregate 'std::stringstream out' has incomplete type and cannot be defined [C++]

Tags: c++, syntax, sstream

I am new to c++ please help me figure out what is wrong with this

```
string c;
stringstream out; //aggregate 'std::stringstream out' has incomplete type and cannot be //defined
out << it->second;
out << end1;//'end1' was not declared in this scope
c = out.str();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing an include for stringstream. On top of that you have a typo

```
out << end1;
```

should read

```
out << endl;
```

`l` instead of `1`.

Comment: i dont see a difference sorry

Comment: I updated my answer to make it clearer. Font makes it difficult to see the difference, but there is one.

Answer (score 29):

Did you:

```
#include <sstream>
```

Also, the second to last line should be `endl` (nb: lower-case L) not `end1` (number one).

The code below compiles and works correctly with G++ 4.2.1 on MacOS X

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
        std::stringstream out;
        out << "foo" << std::endl;
        std::string c = out.str();
        std::cout << c;
}
```

Omitting the `#include <sstream>` causes exactly the same error on my system as your first error.

Answer (score 5):

It's an lowercase `L` and not `1`:

```
out << endl;
```

I think @Bo is right, (sorry and thanks) change it to `std::stringstream out;`

Comment: that was the second error thanks, what about the stringstream?

Comment: `stringstream` is the superclass and you can't use it directly. Use `istringstream` or `ostringstream` instead.

Comment: `stringstream` is perfectly fine to use, you just have to call it `std::stringstream`.

Comment: he's clearly got the namespace imported or the error would have been different.

Comment: I don't think he needs std::stringstream. Rather, I think he's missing the header <sstream>.

Comment: That tip was in my original answer but I removed it since the OP complaint the error was still happenning.